# Kendo MVC Grid - Dropdown with inline editing

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, inline-editing

i have searched all over for a solution and tried many of the advises that was given (just saying if you think I'm too lazy)
I'm a bit of a Kendo noob, so not sure what I'm missing?

As the title say, I got a grid of items and want to edit them inline.  all works fine, but it seems that my editor template just get ignored and 2 inputs get shown when in edit mode (since the child object that must be selected is a complex object with Id and Name properties)

ps: sorry bout formatting. seems my browser don't show this windows toolbar?
Kendo MVC Grid

```
Html.Kendo().Grid<MyViewModel>()
    .Name("Grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.Id).Hidden(true);
        columns.Bound(o => o.Product).EditorTemplateName("ProductsListTemplate");
        ...other columns
        columns.Command(command =>
        {
            command.Edit();
            command.Destroy();
        }).Width(180);
    })
    .AutoBind(true)
    .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create())
         .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InLine).Enabled(true))
    .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .Selectable(sel => sel.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Single)
    .Enabled(true))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(c => c.Id);
            model.Field(c => c.Product).Editable(true);
            ...other fields...
        })
        .Create(update => update.Action("Create", "MyController"))
        .Read(read => read.Action("Read", "MyController"))
        .Update(update => update.Action("Edit", "MyController"))
        .Destroy(update => update.Action("Delete", "MyController"))
    ))
```

ProductsListTemplate.cshtml (in Shared/EditorTemplates, product options are present in the viewdata as IEnumerable )

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
      .Name("MyChildViewModel") 
      .DataValueField("Id")
      .DataTextField("Name")
      .BindTo((IEnumerable) ViewData["ProductOptions"])
      )
```

MyViewModel
    public class MyViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

```
    [Display(Name = "Product")]
    [UIHint("ProductsListTemplate")]
    public MyChildViewModelProduct { get; set; }
```

... other properties

```
public class MyChildViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: can please post the image of your output?

Comment: I see no functionality here for posting a picture?  (SO n00b!)   But it renders 2 textboxes for the 2 properties, instead of a dropdown  (remember my object have id and name properties?)